# Eventing-binding for Left click in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

Which method is used to click left of mouse in selenium using java? Can it be done using action class?

I tried using action class but did not get result.

Comment: what you are trying to do with Left click? usually people will use right click

Comment: A left click is the normal click. Yes. It's part of the Action class and it's called just "click".

Answer (score 0):

**1) Using standard Click Method:**

The click command emulates a click operation for a link, button, checkbox or radio button. In Selenium Webdriver, execute click after finding an element.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("{your-element-id}")).click();
```

**2) Left or Single click in Selenium using Actions class:**

```
WebElement elementLocator = driver.findElement(By.id("{your-element-id}"));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(elementLocator).click().build().perform();
```

**3) Double click in Selenium:**

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
WebElement elementLocator = driver.findElement(By.id("{your-element-id}"));
actions.doubleClick(elementLocator).perform();
```

**4) Right-click in Selenium:**

> *Right Click operation is called Context Click in Selenium.*

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
WebElement elementLocator = driver.findElement(By.id("{your-element-id}"));
actions.contextClick(elementLocator).perform();
```

**Event Listeners:**

> Webdriver events are helpful to view the events triggered by webdriver.
>
> WebEventListener extends AbstractWebDriverEventListener.

```
    @Override
    public void beforeClickOn(WebElement element, WebDriver driver) {
        //Do Something!!!!
    }
    @Override
    public void afterClickOn(WebElement element, WebDriver driver) {
        //Do Something!!!!
    }
```